# JQuery autocomplete - reset hidden input field

Tags: html, jquery

I am using jquery autocomplete on my form which returns a `label` for the `input` tag and a `value` for a related `hidden` tag. This works perfectly for the searches I do with serached values echoed back into the form.

The problem arises when the user blanks out the `label` text in the input field using the cursor and leaves the field blank. While `label` now has no value (correct) the `hidden` element still has the previous `value` which continues to be used in searches (incorrect). How do I get rid of the `hidden value` when the user blanks out the data in the related input field?

```js
$( function() {

 // Single Select
 $( "#locations" ).autocomplete({
  source: function( request, response ) {
   // Fetch data
   $.ajax({
    url: "getlocations.php",
    type: 'post',
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
     search: request.term
    },
    success: function( data ) {
     response( data );
    }
   });
  },
  select: function (event, ui) {
     // Set selection
     $('#locations').val(ui.item.label); // display the selected text
      $('#location').val(ui.item.value);
     return false;
  },
  focus: function(event, ui){
     $( "#locations" ).val( ui.item.label );
      $('#location').val(ui.item.value);
     return false;
   },
 });

});
```

```html
<input name="locationname" id = "locations" 
value="<? echo $locationname; ?>" placeholder="City ...">

<input type="hidden" id="location" name="location" 
value="<? echo $location; ?>">
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Sounds like you want to have a `blur` callback, that checks if the value is empty and clears the value from the hidden element. You will need to assign `.blur()` callback to the `$("#locations")` element, not in the Autocomplete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following example.

```js
$(function() {
  // Single Select
  $("#locations")
    .blur(function() {
      if ($(this).val() == "") {
        $("#location").val("");
      }
    })
    .autocomplete({
      source: function(request, response) {
        // Fetch data
        $.ajax({
          url: "getlocations.php",
          type: 'post',
          dataType: "json",
          data: {
            search: request.term
          },
          success: function(data) {
            response(data);
          }
        });
      },
      select: function(event, ui) {
        // Set selection
        $('#locations').val(ui.item.label); // display the selected text
        $('#location').val(ui.item.value);
        return false;
      },
      focus: function(event, ui) {
        $("#locations").val(ui.item.label);
        $('#location').val(ui.item.value);
        return false;
      },
    });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<input name="locationname" id="locations" value="City 1" placeholder="City ...">
<input type="hidden" id="location" name="location" value="1001">
```

If the User clears the value and then leaves the field, `blur` event will be triggered. The assigned callback will clear the hidden field.

Comment: Thanks @Twisty. Works perfectly! I also realsied I could have handled this in the script that the form calls but yours is a neater solution.